# Lucene: how to index file names

Tags: java, lucene

I'm newbie lucene user and trying to get some basics now.

I have three files:

- `apache_empty.txt` (empty file),
- `apache.txt` (contains many of `'apache'` tokens),
- `other.txt` (contains just one token - `'apache'`)

When I try to search `'apache'`, **I get only** `apache.txt` and `other.txt` in result, but I wanna get even the `apache_empty.txt` file, which has the searched word in its name...

And that's how I add documents to the index:

```
protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception 
{
  Document doc   = new Document();
  Field contents = new Field("contents", new FileReader(f));
  Field parent   = new Field("parent",   f.getParent(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
  Field filename = new Field("filename", f.getName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
  Field fullpath = new Field("fullpath", f.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
  filename.setBoost(2.0F);
  doc.add(contents);
  doc.add(parent);
  doc.add(filename);
  doc.add(fullpath);
  return doc;
}
```

How to let the lucene index also file names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable wildcards you should search for `apache*` which would also match your filename `apache_empty` for the complete syntax see also [Apache Lucene Query Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html).

An alternative would be to include the underscore as a word separator in the used analyzer.

Comment: Aha, thanks! There is one other problem, because I've parsed only "contents". When I'm parsing filename `QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "filename", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));`, it works exacty as you said... Can you tell me, how can I parse over contents and even over filename?

Comment: @gaffcz Perhaps you've an issue with new FileReader(f), I only add content from a database like `doc.add( new Field( "content", stringRepresentationOfCOntent, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED ) );` try to load the file content in a string, or debug the FileReader part.

Comment: This is the correct way: `MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser (Version.LUCENE_36, new String[] {"filename", "contents"}, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));`. Anyway, thanks!